# Failed ubuntu-windows8 dual boot: Is uninstalling ubuntu the answer?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 13.04, windows-8

I have an Acer Aspire E1-472G with windows 8.1
So after installing ubuntu, something went wrong and I could not boot into windows8.1 and I cannot access my files in any drive except for my ubuntu drive. I'm thinking I'll remove the ubuntu OS for now. Can this solve my problem? Will I be able to boot into windows again? I found instructions online on how to remove ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you have two options:

1. You run a [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) via live media and it fixes everything.
2. You uninstall Ubuntu, insert a Windows recovery disc, and use it to repair your booting problem.

Comment: Boot-repair didn't work though. I will try number 2 Thanks!

Comment: Any time. Let me know how it goes. :D